# adding permanent custom environment path variable

Tags: command-line, bash, swap, environment-variables, bashrc

i am trying to create a permanent path variable following this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/JLjF75b-vMI?t=126 everything worked fine and i was able to cd to my newly added variable's directory, however when i rebooted.

```
xxxx@XXXXXX:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/media/xxxx/System/___HOU
xxxx@XXXXXX:~$ echo $HOU
/media/xxxx/System/___HOU
**xxxx@XXXXXX:~$ cd $HOU
bash: cd: /media/xxxx/System/___HOU: No such file or directory**
xxxx@XXXXXX:~$
```

*i am ubernoob in linux

any help? :)

Comment: I'll take a stab and say it's permissions. Can you compare the permissions of a directory location that DOES fit in the path to the new directory location that you created?

Comment: would you be so kind to guide me to a step by step process guide somewhere how to do that?

Comment: Why would it be a permission problem? The error message says "No such file or directory". It does not mean there's a permission problem, it means there's no such file or directory. Start to walk the filesystem from the root, step into one subdirectory at a time, you'll see which one is missing.

Comment: Is that "System" resource mounted?

Comment: yes the location exists, because i have created that path and if i cd to that path it works:
xxxx@XXXXXX:~$ cd /media/xxxx/System/___HOU
xxxx@XXXXXX:/media/mano/System/___HOU$

and i think the system drive is always mounted on every restart
https://imgur.com/a/n5ZV0Ms